# Contacting another iPhone user

Tags: iphone

I am texting another iPhone user but it’s not saying "delivered," yet when I call, I’m able to leave a voicemail.

Comment: Perhaps the other iPhone user has not set up Messages. On that iPhone: Settings > Messages > Send & Receive.

Comment: They may have 'read receipts' switched off. I'm not certain if this also affects 'delivered' notifications.

Comment: A voicemail has nothing to do with whether the phone even exists, let alone up and functioning.  Voicemail is all provided by the carrier.  The act of delivering an iMessage, though, requires the phone (well, some client logged into that AppleID) to be up and functional.